# Detect if subscription is cancelled automatically

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I have setup my Stripe subscriptions to be automatically cancelled after 3 failed payment attempts and I have a `customer.subscription.deleted` webhook to record the cancelled subscription.

Is there a way to detect in the `customer.subscription.deleted` webhook if the subscription is cancelled by Stripe because of failed payment attempts OR manually cancelled through the Stripe dashboard OR cancelled because of an API request made from our application?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't differentiate between the last two cases, as the dashboard itself uses the API.

However, you can differentiate between automatic and manual cancelations. Simply look at the [`request`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-request) attribute in the [`customer.subscription.deleted`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted) event's body.

If the subscription was canceled automatically after too many failed payments, then `request` will have a null value.

Otherwise, if the subscription was canceled through the API or the dashboard, `request` will have a non-null value: the request ID (`"req_..."`) of the [subscription cancelation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription).

EDIT: as Yoni Rabinovitch pointed out, the above is true if the subscription was canceled with `at_period_end=false` (or no [`at_period_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription-at_period_end) parameter, as `false` is the default value).

If the subscription was canceled with `at_period_end=true`, then a `customer.subscription.updated` event would be fired immediately (to reflect the fact that the subscription's [`cancel_at_period_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object-cancel_at_period_end) attribute is now true), and that event's `request` would have the request ID of the subscription cancelation request.

However, the `customer.subscription.deleted` event that would be sent when the subscription is actually canceled at the end of the billing period would have `request=null`, just like an automatic cancelation after too many failed payements.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks you so much. "request" attribute will make the work done for me. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see the request attribute in the customer.subscription.deleted event is null if the subscription is cancelled automatically at the end of its period because cancel_at_period_end was set to true on the subscription. Therefore it would seem that checking the "request" attribute is not sufficient for determining that the subscription was cancelled due to failed payments.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch You're absolutely correct. I edited my answer to specify what happens in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If you instead cancel a subscription at the end of the billing period, a **customer.subscription.updated** event is immediately triggered. That event reflects the change in the subscription’s **cancel_at_period_end** value. When the subscription is actually canceled at the end of the period, a **customer.subscription.deleted** event then occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You can now differentiate the two cases (manually cancelled vs payment failed) using the `cancellation_details.reason` field on the subscription object sent by the `customer.subscription.deleted` webhook.

As of 9/13/2023 there are 3 possible reasons: `cancellation_requested`, `payment_disputed`, and `payment_failed`.

Stripe documentation - https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-cancellation_details-reason

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same questions, Based on the answers found here I was able to create this snippet of code, it covers all the cases on the original question:

```
    try {
        \Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        \Stripe::setApiVersion(config('services.stripe.version'));

        $endpoint_secret = config('services.stripe.invoice_webhook_secret');
        $request = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'] ?? null;

        $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
            $request,
            $signature,
            $endpoint_secret
        );

        //$event->type is: "customer.subscription.deleted"
        //Keep in mind that you can change the settings in stripe 
        //so failed payments cause subscriptions to be left as unpaid instead
        //of cancelled, if those are your settings this event will not trigger

        $subscription = $event->data->object;

        if ( !empty($event->request->id)) {
            //the request was made by a human


        }elseif ( !empty($subscription->cancel_at_period_end)) {
            //the request was empty but the subscription set to cancel
            //at period end, which means it was set to cancel by a human


        }else{
            //the request was empty and
            //NOT set to cancel at period end
            //which means it was cancelled by stripe by lack of payment


        }

    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else looking for this since this is the first result that comes up in google.